# Best way to do a high frequency loop in python on Linux?

Tags: python, linux, python-3.3

How can I best create a high frequency, 100 times a second, loop in python on Linux? It does not need to be highly accurate, just good enough so on average does actually loop about 100 times a second.

I tried:

```
import time
count = 0
start = time.time()
while count <= 300:
    time.sleep(0.01)
    count = count + 1
end = time.time()
print('avg. {0}'.format((end - start) / count))
```

And it works pretty well! Getting

```
avg. 0.0103...
```

output.

But is there a better way to do such tight loops?

(This is for a server that needs to frequently read incoming network packets and process them, *and perform periodic processing whether there are new packets or not*).

Comment: You should probably use the [`select`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/select.html) module to wait for I/O instead of using such tight loops

Comment: It's unusual that you would want to sleep like this ... Can you tell us *why* you want to do this?  There might be a better solution...

Comment: When you say "better", what do you mean exactly?

Comment: Probably your task could be implemented with the observer pattern. Aka publish/subscribe or event/listener pattern. Depending on your needs you could look at `select` as suggested by lanzz or PyDispatcher.

Comment: aha `select` sounds like the way, however the reason I liked doing it in a tight loop on other platforms is because their async option resulted in the event being called on another thread (and the thread safety become complex) - does `select` stay on the same thread?

Comment: oh I see it just blocks, which I realise is OK now that I writing a server, if someone fleshed using select in an answer I could mark it so, thanks!

Comment: You may want to check out D.J. Bernstein's tcpserver (see http://cr.yp.to/ucspi-tcp/tcpserver.html). Basically, you can simply run your program under tcpserver, and tcpserver will handle everything as far as setting up the sockets, listing for incoming connections on whatever port you are using, etc. Incoming data to the socket gets piped to your program's stdin, outgoing data from stdout gets sent through the socket.  This way, you can concentrate on your program's core logic (and simply read/write to stdout/stdin), and let tcpserver handle all of the heavy lifting as far as the sockets, etc.

Comment: @mti2935 not using TCP

Comment: Update the question, my original question still stands - I need a loop because I need perform periodic processing frequently so `select()` which blocks will not do.

Comment: @markmnl You could use select with a timeout to do the periodic processing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you are on UNIX, you can also use the `signal` module.

```
def handler(signum, frame):
    print 'do it'

# This will fire an ITIMER_REAL signal every 0.01 seconds
signal.setitimer(signal.ITIMER_REAL, 0, 0.01)

# Tell the signal module to execute handler when upon signal
# ITIMER_REAL
signal.signal(signal.ITIMER_REAL, handler)
```

For more info see: https://docs.python.org/2/library/signal.html. I have used signals in my own code. I found it highly robust and accurate but somewhat limited in scope (you can only set a limited number of signals). A big advantage is that you do not need threads for concurrency. Be aware, that when you combine multi-threaded code with signals, you must take good care that you set the signal handler (`signal.signal`) in the main thread.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a simple ad-hock solution without drift:

```
import time
INTERVAL = 0.01
last = time.time()
while True:
    next = last + INTERVAL
    time.sleep(next - time.time())  # it's ok to sleep negative time
    last = next
    do_your_thing_here()
```

Answer (score 1):

This is for Pygame only but at the end of the loop you could do...

```
mainClock = pygame.time.Clock()
mainClock.tick(100)
```

100 or 1000 or whatever really.

Comment: I don't know but it goes at exactly 100 FPS or (If my computer is too slow...) Less.